# How to make my site use clean urls?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, clean-urls

The code I have below makes links such as "site.com/image.php?id=12", but does anyone have any tips on making it make links such as "site.com/image/12" or something similar, without manually making a page for each individual id?

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tabl1 where name like '%$s%'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo "<a href='image.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

I have code on the image.php page that looks something like

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM celeb where id like '$id'");
```

that uses the id from the ?id=12 part on my website, so I'm not sure how that would work if I did change it to clean urls.

Any help would be useful, I am kind of a newbie to php here.

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^image/id/([^/]*)\.php$ /image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I created a .htaccess file and put that in it, yet when I click on the link it still goes to image.php?id=12 Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything else I must do?

Comment: google this keyword: apache mod_rewrite

Comment: I've read about that with no success. Would I have to change anything about my php code?

Comment: If you configure apache with mod_rewrite properly then no, you will not need to change your code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site does the work for you
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

```
The original URL:
http://site.com/image.php?id=12
The rewritten URL:
http://site.com/image/12

htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image/([^/]*)$ /image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^image/id/([^/]*)\.php$ /image.php?id=$1 [L]`
I created a .htaccess file and put that in it, yet when I click on the link it still goes to image.php?id=12
Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything else I must do?

Comment: Are you URL you're going to `http://site.com/image/12`? Or `http://site.com/image.php?id=12`, and expecting it to go to `http://site.com/image/12` automatically

Comment: No that was what I meant, sorry about the mixup. Accepting answers is great so that others know they can move on to the next question ^^